# java - how to combine very similar methods

Tags: java, android

I have these two methods that are almost identical. The only difference is the method signature. The last parameter can be a an Object or it can be a list of Objects. I feel like there is a way to combine these but i don't know how.

```
public Query where(String selection, String operator, Object value) {


        WhereClause clause = null;

        try {

            if (!columns.contains(selection)) {
                throw new Exception("No such field for the " + model.getClass().getSimpleName() + " model: " + selection);
            }

            clause = new WhereClause(selection, operator, value);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            clause = null;
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (clause != null) {
            clauses.add(clause);
        }

        return this;
    }

    public Query where(String selection, String operator, List<Object> values) {

        WhereClause clause = null;

        try {

            if (!columns.contains(selection)) {
                throw new Exception("No such field for the " + model.getClass().getSimpleName() + " model: " + selection);
            }

            clause = new WhereClause(selection, operator, values);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            clause = null;
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (clause != null) {
            clauses.add(clause);
        }

        return this;
    }
```

Comment: Throwing and catching exceptions are costly; don't throw one just for the stack trace and to use in flow control. Does an Android user really want to see a stack trace? Can he even do so?  If you want to throw an exception, write your own named subclass of `Exception`.

Comment: do you think i should just log that message then?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Android; I'm not sure who could read the message.

Comment: ah ok. Well i'm attempting to write a framework for future use and the experience. I plan on making it public for others to use and get criticism/feedback. So others would see the stack trace and logs when developing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public Query where(String selection, String operator, Object value) 
{
    ArrayList<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
    list.add( value );
    return where(selection, operator, list);
}
```

Edit:

In case you missed Eric's comment you can also use:

```
List<Object> list = Collections.singletonList(value)
return where(selection, operator, list);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap the last parameter of the first method in a singleton-list (as suggested by  Eric Jablow) and let method 2 do all the work:

```
public Query where(String selection, String operator, Object value)
{
    List<Object> v = Collections.singletonList(value);

    return where(selection, operator, v);
}
```

Comment: `List<Object> v = Collections.singletonList(value)` would be better.

Comment: Good to know... Haven't used that one before. Thanks!